SharePoint - Using MS Graph, how can I determine that a document library/drive is set to require checkout?
I need to use the Microsoft Graph API to determine whether a document library is set to "require checkout".

Unfortunately, there isn’t a direct Microsoft Graph API endpoint that explicitly returns the “require checkout” setting.
